# Change in Emoji Appearance on Telegram After 50 Uses: Is It Code-Related?

Tags: user-interface, encoding, telegram, emoji, mobile-application

I've noticed an unusual behavior in Telegram where, after using an emoji more than 50 times, its appearance changes starting from the 51st instance. This has led me to wonder if this change is due to the way Telegram's code handles emojis after a certain usage threshold. Is there an underlying coding reason for this behavior in Telegram's emoji rendering or encoding? Has anyone else observed this issue or knows why it happens?